# Browser emulation not availble in ie11

Tags: internet-explorer, emulator

My ie11 emulation option doesn't give me any options to choice from, meaning that I can't view older versions. Has anyone else experienced this?

[image: ie11 emulator]

Comment: Are you using de Developer Channel version or it is the full browser? I had this problem when I installed and Visual Studio were running. Reboot solve my problem.

Comment: as far as i'm aware i'm just using the full browser

Comment: It's still not working

Comment: I have this issue @totneschap did you resolve it? I have IE11.0.9600.17501 update 11.0.15. I have VS 10 12 & 13 also on this machine.

Comment: Hi @dewd , unfortunately I have not managed to solve the issue. It used to work on windows 7 but once I was updated to windows 8 it all went down hill from there!

Comment: @totneschap I found an answer on stackoverflow which worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23490161/ie11-developer-tools-document-mode-and-user-agent-string-are-blank Ian Boyd's answer worked for me. Hope it helps you too.